# How can I calculate a deterministic and reproducible checksum of a docker image, locally, without pinging any registry?

Tags: docker, checksum, docker-build

How can I calculate a deterministic and reproducible checksum of a docker image, locally, without pinging any registry?

The checksum should not depend on the image name or in which registry it lives. It should solely depend on the content of all layers.

For example, assume the following:

- a given file `a`
- a dockerfile with the content

  ```
  FROM scratch
  COPY a /a
  ```

Then building the image with `docker build . --no-cache` multiple times should always yield the same checksum.

The regular image ID does not cut it, as it somehow uses content from intermediate containers and hence always changes. I am also aware that since Docker 1.10, images have a "RepoDigest" attribute, which uniquely identifies images based on their layers' content. However, as far as I can tell, that digest is only calculated when pulling or pushing to a registry. Is there a way to get this field without contacting a registry? (and is it actually deterministic, regardless of image name, tag or repo?)

**Basically, I'm looking for a way to run a good ol' sha256sum on a docker image**. This would help me to achieve something similar to as what [can be done with Bazel](https://blog.bazel.build/2015/07/28/docker_build.html): a hermetic build environment, which in turn enables:

- declaring dependencies between docker images, and have a CI system only rebuild what is needed without using docker's cache (assuming that I have a build tool which already manages caches)
- allow me to "sign" images using the same approach as signing classic tarballs (that is, publish a checksum and somehow sign that)
- the big one: enable reproducible builds!

Comment: have the same question - did you get to an answer?

Comment: Have you tried just doing a `docker save -o myimage.tgz my/image:latest` and then running a checksum on that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're working on the same problem that I'm actively solving right now.

The big issue with the question is that container image builds with `docker build` are not deterministic or reproducible unless it happens to reuse the cache from a previous build. A container image build, even with the same filesystem layers, contains metadata on that build, and the metadata contains timestamps:

```json
$ regctl manifest get localhost:5000/library/alpine --platform linux/amd64 --format body | jq .
{
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
  "config": {
    "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json",
    "size": 1472,
    "digest": "sha256:0ac33e5f5afa79e084075e8698a22d574816eea8d7b7d480586835657c3e1c8b"
  },
  "layers": [
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
      "size": 2814559,
      "digest": "sha256:df9b9388f04ad6279a7410b85cedfdcb2208c0a003da7ab5613af71079148139"
    }
  ]
}

$ regctl blob get localhost:5000/library/alpine sha256:0ac33e5f5afa79e084075e8698a22d574816eea8d7b7d480586835657c3e1c8b | jq .
{
  "architecture": "amd64",
  "config": {
    "Hostname": "",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "/bin/sh"
    ],
    "Image": "sha256:d49869997c508135352366cebd3509ee756bba1ceb8eef708a4c3ff0d481084a",
    "Volumes": null,
    "WorkingDir": "",
    "Entrypoint": null,
    "OnBuild": null,
    "Labels": null
  },
  "container": "b714116bd3f3418e7b61a6d70dd7244382f0844e47a8d1d66dbf61cb1cb02b2b",
  "container_config": {
    "Hostname": "b714116bd3f3",
    "Domainname": "",
    "User": "",
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "Tty": false,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Env": [
      "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
    ],
    "Cmd": [
      "/bin/sh",
      "-c",
      "#(nop) ",
      "CMD [\"/bin/sh\"]"
    ],
    "Image": "sha256:d49869997c508135352366cebd3509ee756bba1ceb8eef708a4c3ff0d481084a",
    "Volumes": null,
    "WorkingDir": "",
    "Entrypoint": null,
    "OnBuild": null,
    "Labels": {}
  },
  "created": "2022-04-05T00:19:59.912662499Z",
  "docker_version": "20.10.12",
  "history": [
    {
      "created": "2022-04-05T00:19:59.790636867Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:5d673d25da3a14ce1f6cf66e4c7fd4f4b85a3759a9d93efb3fd9ff852b5b56e4 in / "
    },
    {
      "created": "2022-04-05T00:19:59.912662499Z",
      "created_by": "/bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD [\"/bin/sh\"]",
      "empty_layer": true
    }
  ],
  "os": "linux",
  "rootfs": {
    "type": "layers",
    "diff_ids": [
      "sha256:4fc242d58285699eca05db3cc7c7122a2b8e014d9481f323bd9277baacfa0628"
    ]
  }
}
```

Both the "created" and "history" steps have timestamps that will be unique to the build. Changing those timestamps changes the digest of the config blob, which changes the digest of the image manifest.

The next issue you'll run into is that json serialization would need to be canonical. Some tools will use pretty formatting like `jq`, others will eliminate all unneeded whitespace for compactness, the order of listing multiple keys in a map doesn't need to be alphabetical, etc. So you need to ensure the same tool is always used for serialization and it has canonical output.

To build without pushing to a registry, you can have docker's buildkit output to an OCI layout tar file:

```
docker build --output type=oci,dest=/path/to/file.tar .
```

And in that tar, you will find an index.json with the digest of an image manifest as it was created by buildkit. I've been taking this a step further with regclient's image modification features, changing timestamps (in my case to the git commit time) and stripping other mutable values from the build. Then I verify the result matches a previous build.

Tools like `cosign` will allow you to sign an image using a digest rather than depending on the image in the registry, even before that image has been pushed.

The image mod feature in regclient is still very much a WIP, but you can see the current features here:

```
$ regctl image mod --help
EXPERIMENTAL: Applies requested modifications to an image

Usage:
  regctl image mod <image_ref> [flags]

Flags:
      --annotation stringArray        set an annotation (name=value) (default )
      --annotation-base stringArray   set base image annotations (image/name:tag,sha256:digest) (default )
      --buildarg-rm string            delete a build arg (default "")
      --buildarg-rm-regex string      delete a build arg with a regex value (default "")
      --config-time-max string        max timestamp for a config (default "")
      --create string                 Create tag
      --data-max stringArray          sets or removes descriptor data field (size in bytes) (default )
      --expose-add stringArray        add an exposed port (default )
      --expose-rm stringArray         delete an exposed port (default )
      --external-urls-rm              remove external url references from layers (first copy image with "--include-external") (default )
  -h, --help                          help for mod
      --label stringArray             set an label (name=value) (default )
      --label-to-annotation           set annotations from labels (default )
      --layer-rm-created-by string    delete a layer based on history (created by string is a regex) (default "")
      --layer-rm-index uint           delete a layer from an image (index begins at 0) (default )
      --layer-strip-file string       delete a file or directory from all layers (default "")
      --layer-time-max string         max timestamp for a layer (default "")
      --replace                       Replace tag (ignored when "create" is used)
      --time-max string               max timestamp for both the config and layers (default "")
      --to-oci                        convert to OCI media types (default )
      --volume-add stringArray        add a volume definition (default )
      --volume-rm stringArray         delete a volume definition (default )

Global Flags:
      --logopt stringArray   Log options
      --user-agent string    Override user agent
  -v, --verbosity string     Log level (debug, info, warn, error, fatal, panic) (default "warning")
```

The other part of the puzzle is to make RUN steps reproducible. That's less trivial since not only do the files have timestamps, but the contents of the files being created could have timestamps or other mutable content, and the commands could pull from external mutable sources. Solving that part of the problem is still a work in progress for me.

Answer (score 0):

For a docker image, named "hello-world":

```
docker save --output hello-world.tar hello-world

sha256sum hello-world.tar
```

It should give you the content sha of image.

Answer (score -1):

This should be what [Sigstore](https://www.sigstore.dev/) is for. It is made up of three projects:

- [Cosign](https://github.com/sigstore/cosign), which signs software.
- [Fulcio](https://github.com/sigstore/fulcio), a certificate authority that lets anyone access short-lived certificates via OpenID Connect.
- [Rekor](https://github.com/sigstore/rekor), a secure log of signing events that allows you to verify the provenance of software artifacts.

You can then follow "[Keyless Sign and Verify Your Container Images With Cosign](https://www.appvia.io/blog/tutorial-keyless-sign-and-verify-your-container-images)" ([Chris Nesbitt-Smith](https://www.appvia.io/blog/tutorial-keyless-sign-and-verify-your-container-images))

> Behind the scenes, cosign creates the keypair ephemerally (they last 20 minutes) and gets them signed by Fulcio using your authenticated OIDC identity.
> That is OIDC: OpenID Connect 1.0 is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol.
>
> OIDC allows:
>
> - Clients to verify the identity of the End-User based on the authentication performed by an Authorization Server,
> - as well as to obtain basic profile information about the End-User in an interoperable and REST-like manner.
>
> [image: https://www.appvia.io/media/pages/blog/tutorial-keyless-sign-and-verify-your-container-images/b34510f730-1636070503/keyless-signing-1600x.png]

```
COSIGN_EXPERIMENTAL=1 cosign sign image:tag
COSIGN_EXPERIMENTAL=1 cosign verify image:tag
```

But you would need to setup your own local OCI registry in order to keep the all toolchain local, since cosign stores signatures in an OCI registry, and uses a naming convention (tag based on the sha256 of what we're signing) for locating the signature index.

[image: oci registry -- https://github.com/sigstore/cosign/raw/main/images/signatures.dot.svg]

Comment: thank you for the elaborate answer, but if I understand correctly this still requires communicating with a registry (which I can set up to be running on my local machine). I am looking for a solution that does not require interaction with another service. Really just a way to sha256 all layers

Comment: @JakobOdersky I understand. I just wanted to point out the current standard which is being deployed across the software supply-chain these days.

Comment: See also 2023 Oct.: [GitHub: npm provenance general availability](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-09-26-npm-provenance-general-availability/) and more generally "[About security hardening with OpenID Connect](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect)", as well as [npm: Generating provenance statements](https://docs.npmjs.com/generating-provenance-statements). Still depends on a registry...